# Issue with IE11 multi-height TH and positioning of pseudo elements

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to add few icons on the `<th>` by putting them to `position: relative` and then `position`ing the icons as `::after` pseudo element using `position: absolute` inside the `<th>` and giving the icons as background (since they are sprites). This works perfectly in Google Chrome and Firefox, but not in Internet Explorer.

Here's the snippet that demonstrates the problem (which is reproducible only in Internet Explorer, my version 11):

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI';}
.arrow {border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 5px; line-height: 1; background-color: #00f; color: #fff; position: relative; cursor: pointer; padding-right: 20px;}
.arrow-normal::after {width: 9px; height: 12px; margin-top: -6px;}
.arrow-up::after {width: 9px; height: 6px; margin-top: -3px;}
.arrow-down::after {width: 9px; height: 6px; margin-top: -3px; background-position: 0 -6px;}
.arrow::after {
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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");
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="arrow arrow-normal">Two Line<br />Column</th>
      <th class="arrow arrow-up">Single</th>
      <th class="arrow arrow-down">Three<br />Line<br />Column</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 1</td>
      <td>Item 2</td>
      <td>Item 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

When I run this in Google Chrome, I get the expected output:

[image: Google Chrome]

*All the icons in Google Chrome are aligned perfectly in middle.*

Whereas, in Internet Explorer, the problem is, all the `<th>` elements take the right height, when they have different contents, but the positioning is messed up.

[image: Internet Explorer]

What I see is that, in Internet Explorer, the heights are calculated right, but for `position`, the initial heights before adjusting the tables are taken into account. Is there anything that can be done to fix this?

---

**Note 1:** I have also looked into [IE vertical centering bug with table-cell parent and absolutely positioned pseudo-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27278366/ie-vertical-centering-bug-with-table-cell-parent-and-absolutely-positioned-pseud), which requires me to use another element and give `position: relative`, but this is not possible in my case as my HTML is fixed and can't be changed. It is generated by an enterprise application, which I have no control over.

**Note 2:** Since I already know the heights of each element, I am using the negative margin technique.

Please let me know if this is possible.

Comment: This had me shook for the passed day, thanks for taking the time to add this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I was constantly trying out different methods to use `::after` and position it correctly and it looks like none of the methods worked in Internet Explorer 11. So finally I decided using three separate images for the background and positioning it as required.

Here's my updated snippet if someone would use it.

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI';}
.arrow {border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 5px; line-height: 1; color: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding-right: 20px;}
.arrow-normal {background: url("data:image/png;base64,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") right 5px center no-repeat #00f;}
.arrow-up {background: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAkAAAAGCAYAAAARx7TFAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAZdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAHBhaW50Lm5ldCA0LjAuMTZEaa/1AAAAfklEQVQYV2NABj4+Pp6vX7++6+/v7wAVQgVACd/PQPAfCIDUp+DgYDeoFAQEBQUFfAcCkAIY+PLly2e4wqioqPAfP378gsqhAKCJX2NjY/0Zzp07txeo69OLFy+evHz58ikMg/ggcZA8Q2hoKFtxcTF3WloaFzoGiYeGhrIBANcmc5DiPaghAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC") right 5px center no-repeat #00f;}
.arrow-down {background: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAkAAAAGCAYAAAARx7TFAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAZdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAHBhaW50Lm5ldCA0LjAuMTZEaa/1AAAAfUlEQVQYV2NYtWoV85UrV9hwYZA8w6VLl3b8////9a9fv+6j4Xsg8WvXru1g6O/vj/sLBEABDPD79++fCxYsCGMAgZkzZ0YAdf6CyoHBz58/vy1btswPrAAGpk2bFvrjx49vIAUgGkMBDEyZMsX/w4cP9xctWuQBFQICBgYAx8mG6/gP36QAAAAASUVORK5CYII=") right 5px center no-repeat #00f;}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="arrow arrow-normal">Two Line<br />Column</th>
      <th class="arrow arrow-up">Single</th>
      <th class="arrow arrow-down">Three<br />Line<br />Column</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 1</td>
      <td>Item 2</td>
      <td>Item 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Preview**

[image: Internet Explorer]

**Bonus:** The nice part about this is, I have also used something called [CSS background-position edge offsets](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-background-offsets), which helps me in achieving the following stuff, that I did using `right: 5px;` for `::after` pseudo elements in my snippet. Well, I wanted to give a `5px` padding for my arrows to not get stuck to the edge of the table, and I had the following reasons / justifications:

- I am lazy to use Photoshop CS3 to give a padding right to the image and recreate the `data://` URI for the same.
- This is not right, as the image shouldn't have padding inbuilt. What if it is supposed to be used on left side?

By adding the extra bit of:

```css
.class {background: url("image.png") right 5px center no-repeat;}
```

The above CSS offsets the right side of `background-position` for a span of `5px`, which is literally like `right-5px` calculation. Cool, isn't it?

I covered the full experience as [Challenge: Internet Explorer Table Cells & Positioning Nightmare & Alternatives](https://blog.praveen.science/challenge-internet-explorer-table-cells-positioning-nightmare-alternatives/) in my blog post.

> **Note:** This is just an alternative to what I wanted, and I would consider this as a hack-job. I am going to wait till I get a **real solution** to use the `position` and CSS Sprites.

Answer (score 2):

Despite what I said in chat earlier, here's what I wrangled up. It's still not using sprites and positioning, but it might be worth something/helpful to someone:

If you are just wanting arrows, you can use elements instead of replaced content like images. In addition to not using sprites, it also doesn't use any `position` properties. It's still ugly, and includes more convoluted markup, but at least it works in IE11 (you can adjust margins as needed) and you can click/interact with the arrows more easily than you can as background-images:

```css
.arrow {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    line-height: 1;
    background-color: #00f;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.arrow > p {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}
.arrow:last-child > p:last-child {
    margin: 16px 0;
}
.arrow-up {
    border-bottom: 5px solid white;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.arrow-down {
    border-top: 5px solid white;
}
*[class^="arrow-"] {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="arrow">
                <p>Two Line
                    <br />Column</p>
                <p style="margin: 0;"><span class="arrow-up"></span>
                   <br>&nbsp;<span class="arrow-down"></span></p>
            </th>
            <th class="arrow">Single<span class="arrow-up"></span></th>
            <th class="arrow">
                <p>Three
                    <br />Line
                    <br />Column</p>
                <p class="arrow-down"></p>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

I removed the `<tbody>` element from my demo as it was irrelevant to the arrow positioning issue.

Comment: Bro, thanks. I told you I can't change the HTML... `:(`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Ah, dang, I missed that in Note 1.